# Apple push notification with Apple entreprise app don't get the device token

Tags: ios, push-notification, certificate, apple-push-notifications, devicetoken

I set up everything (creates certificates) and figured out to get the device token in development environment.

When I call:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:[UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:(UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge) categories:nil]];
```

I get the device token here:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken
{ ...
```

But with apple entreprise, when I export the app and download it on an iPhone, the **application:didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken** is never called!

I've created :

- an IOS Distribution certificate (with the right App ID)
- an APNS Production certificate (with the right App ID)
- a provisioning profile allowing APN (with the right App ID)

I have the same for the development , and as I said, when I launch the app from xcode, I get the device token. Why not in the exported app?!

Comment: Have you checked reason for failing in `-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:(NSError *)error` ?

Comment: Did you updated the right pem (generated from APNS Production certificate) file to your server to send notification?

Comment: @JakubVano I check by posting the device token to my server and I double check with an UIAlert.

Comment: @Aju I did, but this is the next step, I need first to get the device token

Comment: @DamienRomito I meant: when registration fails, then `didFailToRegister` delegate method is called. Have you checked `error` passed there?

Comment: @JakubVano, no the method isn't called, I added an UIAlert to check it.

Comment: one thing i want to clear here, i am using APNS with enterprise App. so there is no issue with enterprise app. issue may be in your `pem` or `ipa` file .

Answer (score 1):

I had face the similar issue before, Mine was an issue with provision file issue, Xcode wrongly pick *XC Ad Hoc provisioning* or some times Wildcard app provision while generating build  see the image below[image].

With Wildcard app provision push notification will not work. From Xcode 6 has this problem and there is no option to select the right provision from here. But i found another solution for this. 
Right click the archive from Organizer and select show in finder ->

Right click the archive file and select show package content ->

choose product -> Applications .

Here you can see a file with your app name. copy it to a folder somewhere name 
the folder Payload , then compress it, so you have Payload.zip.

Then rename it to Payload.ipa.
hope it will help you.

Comment: This doesn't work and I don't understand why it should works. the app i export is not for Ah Hoc deployment but for Entreprise Deployment. The default provisioning profile selected enable "Push Notifications", it should works... weird

Comment: I suggest you to recheck every place showing right provision including in Organizer , In my case  Wildcard provision was selected, By doing those steps it worked.

Comment: You was right, The default App ID of my provisioning profile was the auto created "Xcode iOS Wildcard App ID". Your method didn't work for me , but I deleted this wildcard app Id and set mine.